# LG Optimus L4 II E440 factory image

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a problem with my LGE440, so i looking for factory images that fits to my mobile phone. I found the Nexus 7 factory images that have the same build number (Build number: JZO54K; Version: Android 4.12 Jelly Bean) as well as the Android operating system build number on my phone.

I wonder if these images are also suitable for LGE440? Or does anyone know where I could find factory images for LGE440?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it does not. I think even think they have same hardware.